# Jquery load() use variable instead of a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the jquery to load a page into a div. like:

```
#('#mydiv').load("http://gowemto.com/index.php");
```

I want to store the url into a variable like this:

```
var myload="http://gowemto.com/index.php";
```

but when I try to call this function `#('#mydiv').load(myload");`
it doesn't work :(
any help? I really need to use variable instead of url inside my function

Comment: You don't need the rogue `"`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo, you have to remove the extra `"`, at the end of the variable myload; try:

```
$('#mydiv').load(myload)
```

if you are storing jQuery in # var (eg noConflict), but I don't think so, your code must be:

```
#('#mydiv').load(myload)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error (extraneous `"` after the variable name), and you should use `$` instead of `#`:

```
#('#mydiv').load(myload");
```

It should be:

```
$('#mydiv').load(myload);
```